# CSS Link Not Working or Something

Tags: html, css

When I run this code, nothing shows up. But on codecademy, it seems to work fine. I'm not sure if it has to do with the link or something, but please help. The answer might be obvious, but I am a beginner so I need help. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Cohrs Kids\Desktop\menu.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id= "one"></div>
      <div id= "two"></div>
      <div id= "back"></div>
      <div id= "createone"></div>
      <div id= "createtwo"></div>
      <div id= "delete"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
     height: 100%
}

#one {
    height: 50%;
    background-color: blue;    
    width: 15%;
    position: relative;
    left:20%;
    top:25%;
}
#two{   
    height: 50%;
    background-color: blue;    
    width: 15%;
    position: relative;
    left:60%;
    bottom:23%;

}
#back{
 background-color: red;  
 height: 10%;
 width: 15%;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 95%;
}
#createone{
   background-color: #99ffff;  
   height: 10%;
   width: 15%;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 52%;
   left: 20%;

}
    #createtwo{
   background-color: #99ffff;  
   height: 10%;
   width: 15%;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 60%;
   left: 60%;

}
#delete{
  background-color: red;
  height: 9%;
   width: 6%;
    position: relative;
   left: 29%;
   bottom:61.5%;





}
```

Comment: Have you checked the paths? Look at the paths and you'll see why it won't work. Supply a relative path to the link.

Comment: you can't do href to C:\  you need to host it from a web directory

Comment: Thanks you, though

Comment: put the css in the folder that all of the html code is in

Comment: One way is to put the .html file in `C:\Users\Cohrs Kids\Desktop` and use `href="menu.css"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should should structure your folder like this:

```
folder
├──── index.html
├──── menu.css
└──── script.js
```

And then reference the css file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css"/>
```

If you simply write the name of the file, like `href="menu.css"`, it will find a file in the same directory with the name `menu.css`.

If you add a slash before it, like `href="/menu.css"` it will go up as far as it can in the file tree and use the file there.

If you add `../` before it, like `href="../menu.css"` it will go up one folder and use the file there.